# Gstreamer does not work with other user than mendel

Tags: linux, bash, gstreamer, google-coral, google-aiy

I have a google coral dev board. I want the gstreamer plugin to work with user other than default user **mendel** .I performed the following steps and ran into problem.

1. Installed the gstreamer using the following command.
   `sudo apt-get install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-good python3-gst-1.0 python3-gi`
2. Then cloned the mendel user in the following script.

```
SRC=$1
DEST=$2

SRC_GROUPS=$(id -Gn ${SRC} | sed "s/${SRC} //g" | sed "s/ ${SRC}//g" | sed "s/ /,/g")
SRC_SHELL=$(awk -F : -v name=${SRC} '(name == $1) { print $7 }' /etc/passwd)

useradd --groups ${SRC_GROUPS} --shell ${SRC_SHELL} --create-home ${DEST}
passwd ${DEST}
```

3. If we save the above file under the name **clone-user.sh**. 
Then use the following command 
  `./clone-user.sh mendel user2`.

4. If we switch to the user created above using `sudo su - user2` and run the command the `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! waylandsink`. Then gstreamer wont work.
5. Where as the command `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! waylandsink` works if we are using a default user. In my case it is **mendel**.

I have tried the  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736528/linux-wayland-display-multiple-user). But it also doesnot work.

Comment: Define `GST_DEBUG=3` environment variable or add `-v` command line options to `gst-launch-1.0` see debug messages.

Comment: I found out the solution  in this [doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JJX1-1DcklfEEyQ5py5Qcyy1fcTYZLRlIfpBRonNiMY/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: But the socket file that is created in the **/run/user/1000** should be also be created for the new user in the directory **/run/user/<id_of_new_user>**  .

Answer (score 0):

You can get the new user's id with:

```
$ echo $UID
```

copy the files from /run/user/1000 to the new user's id:

```
$ cp -r /run/user/1000 /run/user/$UID
```

own it:

```
$ sudo chown username:username -R /run/user/$UID/*
```

set XDG_RUNTIME_DIR:

```
$ export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
```

I'm able to do this and run the `edgetpu_classify` and `gst-launch-1.0` with both mendel and root.

Comment: I agree with your solution , but if look closely the first three lines are not actually required. Because you are setting `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` as `/run/user/1000`. This approach is listed in the document uploaded. The error actually arises when we set  `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` as `/run/user/$UID`.   I have also used  a soft link to the socket file using `ln -s  /run/user/1000/wayland-0  /run/user/1003/wayland-0` .  This approach works. The above socket file is failing when directly copied from `/run/user/1000/`